# how can i fix a php script that stops html page from displaying

Tags: php, forms, scripting, subscription

I have a PHP script in an HTML page that is stopping my entire HTML page from displaying its contents when I remove the following lines, it works perfectly:

```
if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject $message, $header);
    $feedback = 'mail submitted';       
}
```

What could be the problem?

Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
    $to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'From Your Website';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $message = <<<EMAIL
    Hello this is $name my email is  


    $message

    EMAIL;
    $header = '$email';
    if($_POST){
        mail($to, $subject $message, $header);
        $feedback = 'mail submitted';       
    }
?>

//body starts here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test mail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
    <form action="#" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="email" name="email" />
        <textarea type="text" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="su`enter code here`bmit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of if($_POST) try if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) &&  $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    
}

Comment: Also try mail($to, $subject $message); instead of mail($to, $subject $message, $header);

Answer (score 0):

You should try to initialize post with isset.

```
if(isset($name = $_POST['name'])){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
}
```

You trying to initialize variables with post values and you have nothings in post values.